# UITabBarController delegate didselect Item in UIViewContoller

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uiapplicationdelegate

I have added UITabBarController in appdelegate.m.  Please check the below code

```
 DiViewController *contact  = [[DiViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DiViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *contactNav =  [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:contact];
    contactNav.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;


    self.tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    CGRect tabframe = self.tabController.tabBar.frame;
    tabframe.origin.y -= 10;
    tabframe.size.height += 10;
    self.tabController.tabBar.frame = tabframe;
    self.tabController.delegate = self;
    self.tabController.viewControllers = @[contactNav];
```

Then i have arun DiViewController.xib in simulator bottom tab bar opened. Then i have click tabbar item.didSelectViewController working in  appdeletgate.m. But i want in DiViewController.m. Ho can i get didSelectViewController  in DiViewController.m. i have used same below in DiViewController.m but not working.

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{



}
```

Comment: Why do you expect it to just work? Why can't you use `viewWillAppear:`?

Comment: @wain before i'm using the following methos in DiViewController using onclick. But i added the following code  in didSelectViewController appdelegate method.After its not goes to RoomViewController.

Comment: [[PhoneMainView instance] popToView:[ChViewController compositeViewDescription]];
RoomViewController *controller = DYNAMIC_CAST([[PhoneMainView instance] changeCurrentView:[RoomViewController compositeViewDescription] push:TRUE], RoomViewController);
if(controller != nil) {
NSString *a1 = @"sip:";
NSString *a2 = @"test";
NSString *a3 = @"@tes.test.org";
NSString *str =[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@%@", a1, a2, a3];[controller setRemoteAddress:str];}